# Cant start Mysql on bitnami wordpress on EC2

Tags: mysql, wordpress, ubuntu, ssh, amazon-ec2

I am having troubles starting mysql server on a bitnami instance on amazon ec2 through the normal startup scripts (on instance reboot or start) and through ssh
sudo /etc/init.d/bitnami start mysql

i get the following error message using ssh

```
resize2fs 1.42 (29-Nov-2011)
The filesystem is already 2621440 blocks long. Nothing to do!
140530 09:53:27 mysqld_safe Logging to '/opt/bitnami/mysql/data/mysqld.log'.
140530 09:53:27 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld.bin daemon with databases from /opt/bitnami/mysql/data
140530 09:53:27 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /opt/bitnami/mysql/data/mysqld.pid ended
```

checking the attached volumes disk usage is as follows

```
Filesystem Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1 9.9G 3.5G 5.9G 38% /
udev 1.9G 8.0K 1.9G 1% /dev
tmpfs 376M 168K 375M 1% /run
none 5.0M 0 5.0M 0% /run/lock
none 1.9G 0 1.9G 0% /run/shm
/dev/xvdb 16G 167M 15G 2% /mnt
```

Comment: Check this log `/opt/bitnami/mysql/data/mysqld.log` for information on why mysql is not starting correctly.

Comment: i just checked it, however the log is empty

Comment: you should be able to start mysql directly via `service mysqld start` I'm not sure what the bitnami service is trying to do.

Comment: same error, any idea what (The filesystem is already 2621440 blocks long. Nothing to do!) means

Comment: There should be no reason for mysql service to call resize2fs.